# Excel VBA - PivotTable Filter Runtime Error '1004' PivotItems

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot-table

I have the following code, which opens an excel file, selects the sheet and runs a macro - I have then managed to make it remove the filter for Date, but I am then having trouble getting it to filter to `"01/07/2013"`

```
Sub Data()

Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim oSheets As Sheets
Dim oPi As PivotItem
Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
oExcel.Workbooks.Open ("\\A79APBRSFACTD\MDSS\FactivityServer\FactShar\OEE_Daily2.xls")
oExcel.Visible = True
Set oExcel = Excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks("OEE_Daily2.xls")

oWB.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").Select
oExcel.Run ("Update_OEE_Daily")
oWB.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").Range("B3").Select

With oWB.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotItems("01/07/2013").Visible = True
End With

Set oExcel = Nothing
Set oWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

I receive the following error message `Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the PivotItems property of the PivotField class`

The date `"01/07/2013"` is available in the source data of the PivotTable, and I am able to select it manually, but not automatically.

This is baffling me, as I only need it to show the one date.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to show *only* 01/07/2013, then once you've cleared the filter, you need to hide everything *except* 01/07/2013, so try this:

```
With oWB.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each oPi In .PivotItems
        If oPi .Value <> "1/7/2013" Then
            oPi .Visible = False
        End If
    Next pi
End With
```

Make sure you remove the zeros.

If you step through your code, and watch oPi.value, you will see that it is "1/7/2013" instead of "01/07/2013". At least it was for me.

Excel is a nightmare when it comes to regional dates, so if you are using US mm/dd/yyyy format, this should work. If you're using dd/mm/yyyy format, you will need to check oPi.value against an American-formatted date. Annoyingly.

Edited 23/07/2013:

New code to search the data before applying the filter and lots of re-formatting to get around the American date format issue:

```
Sub RunFilter()

    Dim strFilterDate As String
    Dim datFilterDate As Date
    Dim rngDateRange As Range
    Dim c As Range

    strFilterDate = InputBox("Enter the filter date in dd/mm/yyyy format.", "Enter date", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy"))

    If IsDate(strFilterDate) And Len(strFilterDate) = 10 Then
        datFilterDate = DateSerial(Right(strFilterDate, 4), Mid(strFilterDate, 4, 2), Left(strFilterDate, 2))
        Set rngDateRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        For Each c In rngDateRange
            If c.Value2 = datFilterDate Then
                ApplyPTFilter (datFilterDate)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c  
    End If
End Sub


Sub ApplyPTFilter(datDate As Date)

    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim strDate As String

    strDate = Format(datDate, "m/d/yyyy")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OEE Pivot Daily").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each pi In .PivotItems
            If pi.Value <> strDate Then
                pi.Visible = False
            End If
        Next pi

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @dendarii, I've made your change and I no longer get my previous error, but I now get "Run-time error '1004': unable to set the visible property of the PivotItem class". Did you get this? I assume this means it found the value "1/7/2013"? How can I stop this?

Comment: I have stepped through the code with a watch, and have found that oPi.Value returns as "4/26/2013" (the first date in the list) - so I will need to ensure the dates are in m/d/yyyy format before starting the loop

Comment: You could add a search on the Date column to find the specified date and if the search yields positive results, only then would you try to filter the pivot table. Let me know if you would like to search first before applying the page filter.

Comment: Yes - I think having the search could be helpful, so that it can handle missing dates. Do you think this will stop the error for setting the visibility?

Answer (score 2):

I realize that I bumped on similar issue waaay after the original post, although this thread was very inspiring - what helped me was:

```
.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
```

After clearing the retained items from the pivotfilter list - I managed to execute my code without fail, what went after this was:

```
    FiltrArr = Array("wymagalne", "wymagalne na jutro", "przeterminowane", "puste")

    For Each PivotItem In .PivotFields("status").PivotItems
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(PivotItem.Caption, FiltrArr, 0)) Then
            PivotItem.Visible = True
        Else
            PivotItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next PivotItem
```